# Allowing ArcPy script to continue if raster with no projection information encountered?

Tags: arcpy, raster, coordinate-system

How do I allow an ArcPy script to continue if a raster with no projection information is encountered?

---

```
import arcpy, sys, os

InFolder = r"C:\test_in"
OutFolder = r"C:\test_out"
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26918) # NAD83 / UTM zone 18N

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for Ras in rasterList :
     inRaster = os.path.join(InFolder, Ras)
     spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(inRaster).SpatialReference
     if spatial_ref.type <> "Unknown":
          outFileName = "{}.{}".format(os.path.splitext(Ras)[0], "jpg") # Remove .sid and add .tif to Ras filename
          outRaster = os.path.join(OutFolder, outFileName) # Path and Filename of output raster (.tif)
          arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (inRaster, outRaster, OutSR)
```

The code works now.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  You have included a code snippet but not what happens when you run it?  Also, you have deleted all the context for this question and all but stranded the two answers so far.  When you update a question you should try to avoid invalidating any existing answers.  This may often mean that it is better to start a new question.  It may be worth referring back to http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Comment: It works now. I've updated the original question to include the correct code. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the question body now no longer includes the question.  I'll perform an [edit] to try and make that the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try using:

```
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(<your_dataset>).spatialReference
if spatial_ref.type <> "Unknown":
    # Do your processing
```

to create a SpatialReference object from a `dataset` and test whether its type is "Unknown" (rather than "Geographic" or "Projected" which would indicate that it has a spatial reference defined).

Comment: I updated my code (see above) to include your suggestion. I'm getting an error " spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(InFolder).spatialReference
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist". Any suggestions?

Comment: @AnthonyStokes Please keep error messages with the code snippet that they are coming from i.e. in the question rather than comments.  For any error messages make sure you show the full error which includes the line number.

Comment: It works now. I've updated the original question to include the correct code. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyStokes Just take care to observe the protocols that surround our focussed Q&A format.  At the moment your question body contains only the solution.  The idea is for the question to have the problem and the answer(s) to have the solution(s).  It can take a little getting used to but the idea is that we attach our highest priority of helping future visitors to this Q&A.  Helping the original asker is more incidental but nevertheless valuable so I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `arcpy.Describe()` to determine what the current SR is, and if it doesn't have one then skip it.

```
for Ras in rasterList :
    inRaster = os.path.join(InFolder, Ras) # Path and Filename of input raster (.sid)
    currentSR = arcpy.Describe(inRaster).spatialReference
    if currentSR.type != "Unknown":
        #rest of your code here
        outFileName = "{}.{}".format(os.path.splitext(Ras)[0], "tif") # Remove .sid and add .tif to Ras filename
        outRaster = os.path.join(OutFolder, outFileName) # Path and Filename of output raster (.tif)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting ", + Ras)
        arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (inRaster, outRaster, OutSR)
```

Comment: I got the same error of having no projection information when I tried this.

Comment: you've got your `if spatial_ref.type <> "Unknown":` outside your `for` loop.  Take another look at my answer

Comment: I believe I've placed the if `if spatial_ref.type <> "Unknown":` in the for loop correctly now. I'm pretty new to this so I appreciated the help.

Comment: It works now. I've updated the original question to include the correct code. Thanks.